# Slow load of the activity page when using a code

Tags: android

I use a library to encrypt the SharedPreferences

And to load the page you need to get a value from SecurePreferences

But due to the use of this code in the onCreate the page load speed has dropped significantly

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            prefs = new SecurePreferences(getActivity());
```

What a solution to speed up loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Instead of creating that object every time, you can use the dagger to provide the same old object to all instances of activity
- You can observe shared preferences using Rx java to improve performance

  https://proandroiddev.com/observe-sharedpreferences-changes-using-rxjava-f0f3b43c6329
- You can use Async task to do your heavy work in background thread, and publish those results in ui thread

Comment: I want to use Dagger for this but I don't know what code to write because I'm a beginner Please write me the required code

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid running blocking code on the UI thread.
A simple solution could be to wrap loading of the SecurePreferences into an AsyncTask and populating the UI when it is finished.